# Copy data between two servers

Tags: kdb

How to copy a folder  from a server to other servers，and now i download file at local firstly .but the file is large.so want to use kdb method copy file between two servers.could you  please  give me some advise.thanks
For example:

```
`server1:` `name:server1,ip:123.123.12.3,filepath:/opt/test/2019.05.09/`

server2:name:server2,ip:132.132.3.2,filepath:/opt/test/2019.05.09/
```

And now plan copy server1's all files under filepath to server2's filepath. what should i do.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you have direct connection between servers? If yes, I think rsync/scp will be the best way to do.

If you really want to use kdb as a intermediate, what you will do is just simply open a connection between two q session in 2 server using `hopen`. , then call query with the handle and retrieve the data in memory and then save down locally. However, personally I think this is not a efficient way as memory and time consuming. simply using rsync I would say.

Btw next time please include more example for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

so if you are looking to copy files between two remote servers you have a few options.

You could use `scp`. The syntax for copying files between two remote servers would look like this:

```
scp user@123.456.789.123:/path/to/originalfile.txt user@321.987.654.321:/path/to/copiedfile.txt
```

Or if you are using `scp` to send a file from a local machine to a remote server this can be shortened to:

```
scp /path/to/originalfile.txt user@321.987.654.321:/path/to/copiedfile.txt
```

Alternatively you could use `rsync` which works similarly. To copy a file again from a local machine to a remote server you could use the following:

```
rsync /path/to/originalfile.txt user@123.456.789.123:/path/to/copiedfile.txt
```

Of the two, `rsync` is faster as the first time a file is copied, it sends the entire file. However if the file is edited and sent again `rsync` will send only the differences in the two files.

You can accomplish the same results within a q session. The general steps for doing this are:

1.Interpret command line parameters, using defaults if necessary

2.Open a connection to remote HDB

3.Query data by sym for table on date

4.Write data to local HDB

5.Repeat for each sym

6.Repeat across all specified tables and all specified dates